# Facebook iOS SSO froze Facebook app screen

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Facebook iOS SDK 3.0 for my client who is not ready to move to 3.1 yet, and have experienced issues on some occasion.

I basically followed Facebook tutorial / sample, however, sometimes (iphone4S so far only), after user is taken to facebook app for SSO and taken back to my app successfully (with open FBSession and valid access token and everything), the facebook app (when reoponed) is permanently stuck on a white screen with only the blue bar at the top. When user taps on "cancel" on the top blue bar, they got taken right back to our app. User has to completely close facebook app and relaunch before they can use Facebook app normally again.

This problem is NOT always reproducible even on the exact same device. My understanding is that my app pass a fb:// URL that launches Facebook app, and once it's in Facebook app, I have no control or anything and the freezing could not have been caused by my codes at all.

Just want to see if my understanding is correct before I explain to my client... Any thoughts would be helpful... thanks!

Comment: Have you set up the URL scheme with you app id in URL Types in the info-section in your application?

Comment: Hi thanks. Yes I did set it up properly. Have double checked many times. It wouldn't have worked on any device at all if it hasn't been set up anyways I think...